# Console.WriteLine Endpoint in Console/Log

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autosys

So, I'm fairly certain this is a relatively remedial question with a likely simple solution, but I just can't seem to find it. I've currently got a program that writes the variables it sets to the console on execution, as well as writing them to the logfile when called through Autosys.

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Output Variable: " + variable1);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Output Variable: " + variable2);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Output Variable: " + variable3);
```

Simple stuff. But for some reason, when I call this...

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Endpoint: " + endpointAddress);
```

after previously setting

```
endpointAddress = "https://endpointaddress.com";
```

for debug

or

```
string endpointAddress = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENDPOINT");
```

for the Autosys call, with ENDPOINT set in the jobvars file to

```
JV_ENDPOINT https://endpointaddress.com
```

and JV_ENDPOINT set in the cmd file to

```
SET ENDPOINT=%JV_ENDPOINT%
```

with the end result of it pretty much being exactly the same as it is when the program is run through Visual Studio or the executable itself,

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Endpoint: " + endpointAddress);
```

is just skipped entirely in the log. The other ten or so WriteLines that are called all work fine, but nothing at all is written in that line's place.

A few lines up in the log file, I get

```
D:\server_apps\PROCESS_FOLDER>SET ENDPOINT=https://endpointaddress.com
```

showing that the endpoint is properly set, but not calling it later.

And...this just in...the most recent time I have run it, the endpoint line just WAS put into the log file. Huh. Well, let's adjust this question a bit. Would anyone happen to have any idea why this particular line might be so uniquely temperamental? I haven't changed anything significant in more than an hour, so I can't fathom why it would suddenly work. But any insight into why it may have happened (and why it might not again) could go a long way toward working any bugs or kinks out of this. Hopefully.

As always, thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it the last line you write? If so, it's probably simply that the `TextWriter` wasn't flushed/closed. If there is text after the point in the log where you expected to see the output, then the statement is simply not getting executed. Without a good code example, no one can help explain why that would happen.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: The last line written is either `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Method successfully invoked.");`
or 
`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " Failed to invoke Method.");`

This line is near the end, but not the end of it. What more could I add to provide what would be considered a good code example?

I run it a few different ways, sometimes in debug, sometimes not. It doesn't seem to make any difference.